# In my app, am using ViewPager, have 9 Pagess which takes more time to load and also handling webservice call become very tedious

Tags: android, web-services, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Am writing one Android application which have 9 slide Pages, implemented using `ViewPager`. I designed all the screen and added in `PlaceholderFragment` `OnCreateView` `methode` and all are laying out correctly and able to slide them. My problem here is I have 9 different `webservice` call to populate data in each page after user enters some data. I have one Main activity which has inner static  `fragment` class.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{onCreateView.....return View;}
```

and

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

}
```

`SectionsPagerAdapter`, subclass of `FragmentPagerAdapter` class is used to instantiate 9 `views`.

Which is the best way to handle the click events in each fragment. Currently am handling like 
`(MainActivity)(getActivity())).getUpdatedStatus("xxx","xxx")`, which calls the `AsyncTask` class.

By doing so,  `MainActivity` becomes very heavy and total number of lines become 3500+ Now am handling 9 service calls in single `activity`. let me know if more details required.(I cannot post complete code here sorry, due to restrictions)

Comment: where do you call your webservice put your code and delete part of it that must be secured

Comment: public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            switch(this.getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
            {
                case 1:
                {}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to replace the AsyncTask with Android Volley. Once an asynctask is called, it never shutsdown you are probably experiencing heavy spikes when loading your app or even crashes.